# Ensuring a merge between branches happens in one direction

Tags: version-control, mercurial, merge, branch

This morning I discovered that my co-worker had merged the wrong way between two branches in mercurial --we have a ver5 and ver6 branch, with extra files in ver6. Is there any way (a serverside hook probably) to enforce that the children of any ver5 node be from ver5?

Comment: I can see how this can be useful, but it kind of goes against the core principles of a DVCS.

Comment: I actually would love this functionality -- even for projects I was working on by myself. DVCS doesn't necessarily say anything about how branches are related, so I don't think it would go against the core principles at all.

Comment: A core principle of any tool like this should be managing complexity. My interpretation of branches is to provide new features that may not necessarily require to be merged back to the original branch. What I describe isn't some niche situation; how should one simultaneously support a released version while adding new features for the next? I think this is a pretty pedestrian feature. If not, what is the preferred method to do what I describe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than post twice, would my answer to "**Mercurial: allow merge from a release branch to the default one, but not vice versa**" help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/19926324/1025457

Comment: Thanks, I think this is great and even is enforced on the server-side to avoid any mistakes --it should probably be implemented in the client as well to mitigate the issue ASAP.

Comment: Glad you like it.  Enforcing client-side would definitely be desirable, and to be honest would probably be a trivial change to the hook (if not just a reuse).  Our problem has always been how to enforce it being deployed/configured.

Answer (score 3):

Whether you have ver5 merged into ver6 or ver6 merged into ver5 you're still ending up with a child of ver5 that has stuff from ver6 in it.

If, however, you want to avoid a changeset whose branch name is ver5 having *ancestors* that are ver6 you could do that pretty easily with a hook.  Just *where* you put that hook is the tricky part.  If you make it a `pretxnchangegroup` hook you can prevent people from pushing an offending merge into the server-side repo, but they will have already committed it, and maybe some more changes on top of it, and they'll have a hard time figuring out what to do to fix it.  If you can control their local setups you can put in a `pretxncommit` hook that prevents them from committing the merge, but you can't make them run that hook using only Mercurial tools.

The actual hook, whichever type you make it, could use either of these strategies:

- check if the branchname is ver5 and if so make sure no specific file/content from ver6 is presnet

or

- check if branchname is ver6 and if so make sure neither p1 nor p2 has branchname ver5

TL;DR: It's probably more trouble than it's worth -- stick to shaming.

Comment: conflating direction of terms, thankfully you understood what I meant. It looks to be even more annoying then you suggest. Even a client side script could have problems since a checking in follows a merge.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it. It uses a [revset query](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/revsets) to find any merges into `ver5` from `ver6`.

```
hg log -r 'children(p2(::ver5 and ::ver6 and merge()) and branch(ver6)) and branch(ver5)'
```

- `::ver5 and ::ver6 and merge()` finds all merges that are ancestors of both `ver5` and `ver6` branches
- `p2(...) and branch(ver6)` grabs the second parent (incoming changeset) that are on the `ver6` branch.
- `children(...) and branch(ver5)` then grabs the actual merge changeset that is on the `ver5` branch.

[I recently needed to figure this out myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19916743/finding-merges-in-the-wrong-direction), but also needed to ensure that `default` wasn't *indirectly* merged into my release branch, i.e. default -> feature -> release.