# Finding Merges in the Wrong Direction

Tags: mercurial

We have three major releases a year, with co-responding branches: e.g. 2013A, 2013B, and 2013C. When we create each branch, it is started from default. **Changes in each branch should only be merged *forward*, e.g. 2013A -> 2013B -> 2013C -> default.**  We have a push hook on the server that checks if a pushed merge is in the wrong direction, i.e. default -> 2013C, 2013C -> 2013B, etc.

We also have team-specific branches, some of which are working on features for a release, and others which are working on the next release, e.g. default.  While a team is working on a release, they merge to/from the release branch.  When the team is ready to work on the next release, they start to merge to/from the default branch.

The other day we had a situation where a new **developer merged default into his team branch before the team was ready to move on to the next release, then merged the team branch into a previous release**, i.e. default -> TeamBranch -> 2013B.  Unfortunately, our hook didn't take this situation into account.

Essentially, this is what happened:

```
2013B       A---o---o---o---o---B---o
           /     \             /     \
Team      /       o---o---o---C---o---o
         /                   /         \  
Default D---o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o
```

A = Creation of 2013B branch
B = Merge into release branch
C = The bad merge.  We want to detect and prevent these whenever we merge into a release branch.
D = The first common ancestor of the release branch and default.

So, I've re-written our hook to check that when a change is merged into a release branch, it doesn't merge backward.  For each merge into a release branch, I check that there aren't any ancestor merges from a forward branch.  Here's the revset query I'm using:

```
> hg log -r "limit(descendants(p1(first(branch('2013B')))) and reverse(p2(ancestors(branch('2013B'))) and branch('default')),1)"
```

This works.  However, we have a large repository (111,000+ changesets,) and the check takes 30 to 40 seconds. **I wanted to know if there is a quicker/faster/more efficient way of writing my revset query, or another approach I'm not seeing.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sent this same question to the Mercurial mailing list and received an answer.  The `branch()` query is the performance bottleneck.  It causes Mercurial to unroll all the changesets on a branch.  Mercurial doesn't cache the results of this, so each call will unroll changesets.

Instead of using `branch()` I switched to using `descendants()` and `ancestors()`:

```
limit(children(p2(2013BBaseline:: and ::2013B and merge()) and branch(default)) and reverse(::2013B))
```

- `p2(2013BBaseline:: and ::2013B and merge()) and branch(default)` grabs the second parent (the incoming branch) for all merges between the start of the `2013B` branch and its head, and returns just those on the default branch. [1]
- The clause above is then wrapped with `children()` to go back down to the children of that parent.
- `and reverse(::2013B)` then gets the children that are ancestors of the `2013B` branch, i.e. the bad merge(s).
- `limit()` then returns just the first of those bad merges.

The query above takes about 1.5 seconds.

Thanks to Matt Mackall for suggesting the solution.

1. `2013BBaseline` is a tag which identifies the changeset in the `default` branch from which `2013B` branch was created, otherwise I would have had to replace `2013BBaseline::` with:

   ```
   p1(first(branch(2013B)))::
   ```

   to discover the release branch's baseline, and that is not very performant.

Answer (score 0):

To detect the merge `C`, you should be able to use

```
$ hg log -r "parents(branch(Team) and merge()) and branch(default)"
```

This gives you changesets on `default` that were merged into `Team`. If there are any, then someone merged into their team branch by mistake. I think you need to attack this from the point of view of the team branch: you cannot forbid merges to/from the release branch since some of them will be legitimate.

If your team branches follow a consistent naming scheme (they should), then you can use a regular expression with the `branch()` predicate to select them. Something like

```
$ hg log -r "branch('re:team-.*')"
```

would match branches starting with `team-`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't embed the team branch name in my revset query because there are an arbitrary number.  I can't pull it from the incoming changesets, because the merge into the team branch could have already been pushed.

Comment: Can't you match the team branches using a pattern like I suggested?

Comment: No.  Team branches have arbitrary names.  No regular expression will capture all possible combinations. Besides, the `branch()` clause is the bottleneck, so I need to avoid using it, at least until the query has already wittled down the set of changesets.

Comment: @splatteredbits: yeah, I read the answer on the mailinglist. Good that you reposted it here.